# Как перенаправить stdout в файл программно на Go?

Tags: linux, golang, вывод, файловый-ввод-вывод

Заранее извиняюсь, если вопрос слишком простой. Имеется такая функция:

```
package main

import (
        curl "github.com/andelf/go-curl"
)

func json_get(link string) {
        easy := curl.EasyInit()
        defer easy.Cleanup()
        if easy != nil {
                easy.Setopt(curl.OPT_URL, link)
                easy.Perform()
        }
}
```

Как перенаправить STDOUT или даже сам CURL в файл? Перенаправить надо программно, т е без `./main > myfile.out`. ОС - Linux.

Comment: А зачем костылить, когда можно сделать вашим способом через >? Смотрите [англоязычный SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473800/in-go-how-do-i-capture-stdout-of-a-function-into-a-string)

Comment: так это функция!!! Я не хочу заставлять пользователя указывать вручную перенаправление вывода, я хочу делать это самостоятельно из программы!!!

Comment: Вам нужно изменить значение переменной `os.Stdout`

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите [список опций](https://github.com/andelf/go-curl/blob/master/const_gen.go). Я, например, вижу `OPT_STDERR`, `OPT_VERBOSE`, `OPT_FILE`, `OPT_NOPROGRESS` - чтото из этого, думаю, должно помочь. Для прогресса там даже есть [пример](https://github.com/andelf/go-curl/blob/master/examples/progress.go)

---

Нужно использовать stdout/stderr/stdin as is, не переделывая. Переделкой вы сломаете ожидаемое поведение и вызовете негодование уже у специалистов. Правильный подход - обучить неопытных.

Если нужно писать логи, то пишите их в файл отдельно, не трогая стандартные потоки io.